# yandex геокодирование: не находит город

Tags: json, http, yandex-maps-api, geocoding

Привет, всем! Кто-то может подсказать почему яндекс не находит города в Европе. Пробовал обратное и прямое геокодирование:

Нужен HTTP запрос. Вот примеры, что делаю я:

```
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&results=1&geocode=%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%84%D1%83%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&results=1&geocode=50.112076,8.683403
```

В итоге в запросе нет ни одного результата:

```
{"response":{"GeoObjectCollection":{"metaDataProperty":{"GeocoderResponseMetaData":{"request":"Франкфурт-на-Майне","found":"0","results":"1"}},"featureMember":[]}}}
```

Что не так???

Задача состоит в том, чтобы по массиву, координат найти ближайший 1 город (в массиве большинство координат конкретного города/поселка/ и т.д.) И наоборот, по названию города найти его координаты....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно, [ответ от Yandex](http://clubs.ya.ru/mapsapi/replies.xml?item_no=58741):

> Осенью прошлого года для пользователей HTTP Геокодера, отправляющих
>   запросы без ключа, а также для пользователей JS Геокодера, не
>   передающих реферер или ключ, вступили в силу территориальные
>   ограничения. Геокодирование будет доступно в пределах России, Украины,
>   Беларуси, Казахстана, Грузии, Абхазии, Южной Осетии, Армении,
>   Азербайджана, Молдовы, Туркмении, Таджикистана, Узбекистана, Киргизии
>   и Турции. Если вам нужен поиск за границами этих стран, необходимо
>   получить ключ https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/keys/ и отправлять
>   запросы с ним.